# How to get theText for the options tag when using KendoMulti Select

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" role="application">
    <div class="demo-section k-header">
        <h2>Invite Attendees</h2>
        <label for="required">Required</label>
        <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option value="1">Steven White</option>
            <option value="2">Nancy King</option>
            <option value="3">Nancy Davolio</option>
            <option value="4">Robert Davolio</option>
        </select>
        <label for="optional">Optional</label>
        <select id="optional" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
            <option>Nancy King</option>
            <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
        </select>
        <button class="k-button" id="get">Send Invitation</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var optional = $("#optional").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");

            $("#get").click(function() {
                alert("Attendees:\n\nRequired: " + required.value() + "\nOptional: " + optional.value());
            });
        });
    </script>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

How to get the text for the options tag when using KendoMulti Select box? Currently using .value() gives me the value attribute of the options tag.

The example above was taken from and edited from http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript, document.getElemntById().options[index] and InnerHTML as below

**Edited** : To select all, you may use javascript array to bind all records and use join operation to print as single text.. like below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var optional = $("#optional").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");

            var Element= document.getElementById("required");

            $("#get").click(function() {

                 var arr = new Array()
                 for (var i = 0; i < required.value().length; i++) {
                      arr.push(Element.options[required.value()[i] - 1].innerHTML);
                 }

                 alert("Attendees:\n\nRequired: " +arr.join() + "\nOptional: " + optional.value());
            });
        });
```

Comment: i vote up for your answer but when i use multi select it doesn't select all

Comment: Updated! have a check